# iOS6 - Reliably get Reminders and Calendar events updates

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, calendar, reminders

My app is getting Reminders data from the `Reminders.app` and events data from `Calendar.app`.

My app's data needs to be in sync the Reminder.app and Calendar.app how can I achieve this?

At the moment I'm saving an ID for calendar events that I get from the property `- eventIdentifier` from an `EKEvent` (I'm also saving the event title). The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/eventIdentifier) states that this ID most likely will change if the calendar of an event will change. So how would I deal with if the user changes calendar for an event?

Should I search the user's calendars for the event title and if I find it then update the ID for this event? That seems to be the only option that I have.

Dealing with Reminders there doesn't seem to [exist](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKReminder) an ID property for a Reminder. Although `EKReminder` inherits from `EKCalendarItem` which has two ID properties [calendarItemIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendarItem/calendarItemIdentifier) and [calendarItemExternalIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendarItem/calendarItemExternalIdentifier) here I'm not sure on which one to use.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm starting in on integrating with the Reminders app, and the documentation isn't really clear on how to handle event updates.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `calendarItemIdentifier` as ID for the Reminder events. If that ID doesn't exist anymore in the EKEventStore I use the title of the event and other data to look up the event in the EKEventStore to try to find a match. It's definately not fool proof but it's what you have at your hands.